# Jacobian of function returning $m$ evenly-spaced order statistics of an $n$-dimensional vector

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-transformation, ordinal-data, quantiles, order-statistics

Let $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be the transformation that outputs $m$ evenly-spaced order statistics (including the extremes) of $y$.

> What is the Jacobian of this transformation?

## My Attempt

I tried coding this in Python and using automatic differentiation, but unfortunately doesn't seem to work. Hence, I would like to obtain an analytical formula for the Jacobian of this transformation. Essentially the mapping does this:

- Sorts $y$ in increasing order
- Grabs $min(y)$, $(m-2)$-evenly spaced quantiles, $max(y)$ from the sorted vector

Comment: Great question! Just want to make sure you realized that ranking is not a differentiable function, and this is why vanilla AD will struggle. There have been some cool OT approaches to this problem like this one: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.06504.pdf

Comment: Ooh interesting, thank you! I will have a read at that paper :)

Comment: Please tell us why you want to compute this Jacobian.  In some applications it will make sense and is simple: it's a permutation matrix and its absolute determinant is $1$ almost everywhere.  Other applications might assume your transformation is *everywhere* differentiable, in which case you are asking for a mathematical impossibility and need to take a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the min, max, and some quantile is not a differentiable operation by default.

There is literature on implementing those operations in a differentiable way, then you can apply automatic differentiation. Have a look at "Differentiable Ranking and Sorting using Optimal Transport" https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2019/hash/d8c24ca8f23c562a5600876ca2a550ce-Abstract.html